# How do we decide what should be an object

Tags: oop, object-oriented-analysis

An object oriented application is made up of several different objects. Before engineers start writing code for the participating objects:

How does one decide what should be an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is too open as to admit a concrete answer, so let me provide some thoughts that could help you get started.

Let's assume that we are going to use a pure OO language like Smalltalk where everything is an object.

When working with objects for representing some reality (or fantasy) you usually don't try to identify all of them before you start. Instead, you identify the few that first come to mind as good representatives of your domain. For instance, if you are writing an application for modeling some aspects of Chemistry, you might want to start with Atom and Molecule.

Generally speaking, you should try to focus on concrete an important entities from your domain. Do not think in their interactions yet.

Once you have identified the first few objects, you should focus on the inherent behavior of each of them. For instance, if you are modeling a colony of ants, then your Ant objects will have to know how to move around, how to get back to the nest, how to cut or carry a leaf, etc.

As soon as you add more and more methods to your objects you will discover new objects that are required to enhance the behavior of the ones you have identified. For instance, if you are modeling a chess game, and you have already identified the Pawn object, you will soon realize that you need to model the CheckBoard, the CheckGame and so on.

So, the identification of objects is not something you try to address before you start. Instead, it is something that you will naturally discover by the evolution of your model. As your objects mature, i.e., as they learn more things, they will "reveal" which other objects are still missing.

In the course of your modeling you will likely hit some pieces of knowledge you lack. Here is when you need to ask a domain expert, read or study related material, ask questions in fora such as Stack Overflow, etc. In this regard you will find yourself learning more about the domain so you can "explain" your newly acquired knowledge to your objects. In some regards you will feel that your objects are asking you questions that you would have never conceived yourself and all these activities will fruitfully populate your model with an increasing number of classes (or prototypes) and methods.

Comment: Thanks! Currently I am reading Design Patterns Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software. I am on page 18 so I still have much to learn.

Comment: Excellent. Reading books is much better than reading a short answer. Also keep in mind that you have to put in practice what you learn because you will need to shape your own programming style, refining it at every new pice of code you happen to write.

Answer (score 0):

I must say this is a very interesting question, how someone identify the object. Based on my knowledge I would like to say that programmer should not worry about object as it is the representation of something. It is good to relate object oriented programming with real world. So programmer should firstly identify the class which can be the real world entity and then to describe that real world entity we need object.

For suppose you are developing a project for the librarian, who informed you below problem

"As a librarian, I want library management system where there are different types of reader for books, magazines, CDs and DVDs" (something like this)

So developer can easily identify the class based on its real world representation 
classes should be

1. Librarian
2. Book
3. Magazine
4. CD
5. Reader

And object can be Programming C++ book, Advance JAVA book. Hardik is the reader etc.

So, the object is the representation of the real world entity, which has some specific meaning.